# Is it possible to package d3.js into an express api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, d3.js, graphics

Im working on a graphical web crawling project that's using D3 for the graphics package. To encapsulate the graphics of this application I would like to package the D3 I have into a restful api. I want to package some d3.js into this api that i can then call from another server to populate chart images on that served page.  Is this possible? I'm doubtful, but also open to suggestion.

My issue has been figuring a way to return the graphics from the api. I'm inclined to believe that this it's not possible with D3 as it by nature requires asynchronous interaction with an html document (requiring event listeners, functions for building and updating....) . I have not used this package before so I'm not sure about it's limitations/possibilities.

Comment: You want to use d3.js on the server to generate static chart images?

Comment: I want to package some d3.js into an api that i can then call from another server to populate chart images on that served page.

Comment: What do you mean by possible?  I'm sure it is possible but not out of the box.

Comment: d3.js is meant to be a client side library - it can still pull the data for the charts from your server though. the only reason to generate a static image is if the client doesn't support javascript.

Comment: I mean is there a known fairly simple solution. This is a one-off project, the api would not be used beyond the scope of this project so if there is not a fairly simple solution I'll just include it on the server that is also going to be populating the web page.

Comment: You might have a look at d3-node https://github.com/d3-node/d3-node